# Passing multiple arguments in Django custom command

Tags: django

How do I enable a Django custom command to accept multiple arguments? Suppose that my command is to be called `process_data`, and in `myproject/myapp/management/commands/process_data.py` I have the following:

```
class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        alpha = args[0]
        beta = args[1]
```

And then call the command as follows:

```
>python manage.py process_data 5 16
```

I get the error:

```
manage.py: error: no such option: 16
```

This suggests that it sees my second argument `16` as part of `**options`, rather than a second argument in `*args`. How can I ensure that it is processed as an argument?

Answer (score 1):

You don't add options to the management command like this. Check the [Django documentation about writing management commands](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/custom-management-commands/).

Rewriting your example without testing it (it might have typos):

```
from optparse import make_option
class Command(BaseCommand):
    option_list = BaseCommand.option_list + (
        make_option('--alpha',
            action='store',
            dest='alpha'),
        make_option('--beta',
            action='store',
            dest='beta'),
        )

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        alpha = options['alpha']:
        beta = options['beta']
        # ...
```